# How do I align this div inside a table relative to one of the table's cells?

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

This is what I have right now from this code:

```
<table><tr>
    <td><div id="adt"></div></td> <!-- 336x280 ad code -->
    <td id="butw"><div id="butto">Follow @Twitter</div></td> <!-- Twitter Button -->
    <td><div id="ado"></div></td> <!-- 300x600 ad code -->  
</tr></table>
```

(image of the result)

[image]

My goal is to get the Twitter **div** to be aligned underneath the first **TD**.
I'm not sure whether to use CSS to align the div relative to the table cell or if there's another method I'm forgetting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is by moving the Twitter `div` to the next row.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div id="adt"></div></td> <!-- 336x280 ad code -->
        <td><div id="ado"></div></td> <!-- 300x600 ad code -->  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="butw"><div id="butto">Follow @Twitter</div></td> <!-- Twitter Button -->
        <td> <!-- extra TD here --> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```